# openCV 3.0, openCL and meanShiftFiltering

Tags: opencv, opencl

Based on the changes in openCV 3.0 and openCL, I can not seem to get pyrMeanShiftFiltering to work using openCL.   I know that ocl::meanShiftFiltering was supported in openCV 2.4.10.  The two functions below take the same amount of time to execute.

How can I even check which functions in openCV 3.0 are supported under openCL?    Any suggestions?

```
 #include <opencv2/core/ocl.hpp>   //attempting to use openCL
 using namespace cv;
 using namespace ocl;
    void meanShiftOCL()
    {
      setUseOpenCL(true)
      UMat in, out;
      imread("./images/img.png").copyTo(in);
      pyrMeanShiftFiltering(in, out, 40, 20, 3);    
    }


   //not using openCL
   void meanShift()
   {
     Mat in, out;
     imread("./images/img.png").copyTo(in);
     pyrMeanShiftFiltering(in, out, 40, 20, 3);        
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that there is simple way to determine it with given **OpenCV** binaries, but you can recompile **OpenCV** yourself with additional define (can be specified in cmake):

`CV_OPENCL_RUN_VERBOSE`

With this define every function for which **OpenCL** implementation is available will print to console (stdout) the following message:

`<function name>: OpenCL implementation is running`

Regarded to your question - currently `pyrMeanShiftFiltering` doesn't have **OpenCL** implementation, as I know.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.    That's a bummer that pyrMeanShiftFiltering does not have a openCL implementation.    In version 2.4.10 ocl::meanShiftFiltering was available.   Any reason why they took it away?    
\n
Is there any way in the 3.0 documentation to tell if a function is openCL enabled?

Comment: I'm not sure why it was happened - possibly you can [create a feature request](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues) or even add implementation and make pull request. About documentation - I didn't find any possibility to determine whether OpenCL implementation is available...

Comment: As I see, **cuda** version of `pyrMeanShiftFiltering` exists. Also there are **OpenCL**-charged `pyrUp` and `pyrDown`.