# OpenCV 3.0 error include ocl.hpp

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, opencl

I am using opencv 3.0.0 in ubuntu 14.04.
I install the AMD Catalyst Video Driver to use OpenCV with OpenCL.

The /etc/OpenCL/vendor have "amdocl32.icd  amdocl64".icd with "libamdocl32.so" and "libamdocl64.so".

In the opencv cmake file, the OpenCV appears as:

```
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 hal core flann imgproc ml photo video imgcodecs shape videoio highgui objdetect superres ts features2d calib3d stitching videostab
--     Disabled:                    world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev java python2 python3 viz
--   OpenCL:
--     Version:                     dynamic
--     Include path:                /home/eduardo/Install-OpenCV/Ubuntu/OpenCV/opencv-3.0.0/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Use AMDFFT:                  NO
--     Use AMDBLAS:                 NO
--     Use OpenCL:                  YES
```

When I include the ocl.hpp file in my projet (#include ). The compiler return his message:

```
In file included from main.cpp:11:0:
/usr/include/opencv2/ocl/ocl.hpp: In member function ‘cv::ocl::Hamming::ResultType cv::ocl::Hamming::operator()(const unsigned char*, const unsigned char*, int) const’:
/usr/include/opencv2/ocl/ocl.hpp:1170:46: error: ‘normHamming’ was not declared in this scope
                 return normHamming(a, b, size);
                                          ^
/usr/include/opencv2/ocl/ocl.hpp:1170:46: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp:56:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:54,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:48,
                 from /usr/include/opencv2/ocl/ocl.hpp:50,
                 from main.cpp:11:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/hal.hpp:70:5: note:   ‘cv::hal::normHamming’
 int normHamming(const uchar* a, const uchar* b, int n, int cellSize);
     ^
In file included from main.cpp:11:0:
/usr/include/opencv2/ocl/ocl.hpp: At global scope:
/usr/include/opencv2/ocl/ocl.hpp:1932:9: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
         {
         ^
/usr/include/opencv2/ocl/ocl.hpp:1950:9: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
         {
         ^
/usr/include/opencv2/ocl/ocl.hpp:1956:23: error: ‘CvSVMParams’ has not been declared
                       CvSVMParams params=CvSVMParams());
                       ^
/usr/include/opencv2/ocl/ocl.hpp:1956:54: error: ‘CvSVMParams’ was not declared in this scope
                       CvSVMParams params=CvSVMParams());
                                                      ^
make: *** [main.o] Error 1`
```

I need test the erode and dilate filter on GPU.

Do someone know why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

You should not include `ocl.hpp` into projects based on **OpenCV 3.0** for using `ocl::function_name` notation.

**EDIT:** there is [another ocl.hpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/ocl.hpp) in **OpenCV 3.0** - its sense is *completely different* than in **2.4** branch: in the latter case there are all opencl-charged function definitions, and in **OpenCV 3.0** it is platform, context and device related information or tuning. It can be included with this command:

```
#include <opencv2/core/ocl.hpp>
```

Your `ocl.hpp` was taken from `/usr/include/` - it seems that you also have some **OpenCV 2.4.x** development packages installed in your system - it's a different branch, for better clearance please remove all `libopencv*-dev` packages. It will help you (will remove ambiguous headers) if you want to use only **3.0** version.

You should run `make install` after `cmake <your opencv 3.0 source dir>` and `make` - it will install all necessary stuff into your system. By default all headers will be in `/usr/local/include` folder.

Comment: Thanks.

If I can't use ocl.hpp. How can get and set devices?

I don't know if OpenCV really is using OpenCL on erode and dilate functions like this example:

http://opencv.org/platforms/opencl.html

Comment: Now **OpenCV** implicitly uses opencl-charged function versions if it can find available OpenCL devices and libraries. You can actually check if it uses OpenCL for any function only with special **OpenCV** build with flag `CV_OPENCL_RUN_VERBOSE` (for details look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34203627/opencv-3-0-opencl-and-meanshiftfiltering/34213354#34213354)). You can also use any checks from [ocl.hpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/ocl.hpp) - it have *completely different* sense than `ocl.hpp` from **2.4** branch!

Comment: @EduardoMartins: I updated my answer about `ocl.hpp` - sorry for inconvenience, I thought that you tried to use `ocl::function_name` notation available in **OpenCV 2.4.x**.

Comment: Thanks. The 
    #include <opencv2/core/ocl.hpp>
works.

Comment: @EduardoMartins: then I'll appreciate accepting my answer :)